# English question .use of studying and pursuing

Tags: single-word-requests

Studying Masters of fashion management or pursuing master of fashion management which one is correct . When I am writing it into my resume

Comment: I don't think they the two words necessarily have the same meanings.  At university (in the late 1960s!) I studied chemistry, but then I pursued a career as a Patent Attorney (involved with patents related to chemical issues).  The (currently) only answer below suggests that you use "pursuing" because it sounds more formal: I would say that it sounds more pretentious and therefore should be avoided.  Finally, the choice may depend on what country you are in: what is more common / preferred in the USA may not be the same as what's best in UK English.  (I'm in the UK.)

Answer (score 1):

A topic/subject field is something that you study.

A degree or career is something that you pursue.

Therefore, I think you should say "studying fashion management" or "pursuing a master's degree in fashion management". I would not say "studying masters [...]"

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, although "pursuing" sounds more formal. It is also more commonly used than "studying." So, if your question is in regards to your resume, go for "pursuing."

Hope I answered your question.

I recommend the following sites for great grammar info:

http://englishisducksoup.com

http://www.queens-english-society.com

Comment: I would suggest 'pursue studies' is more idiomatic than 'pursue' on its own.

Comment: That was my answer. "Pursuing Master's in FM." I think "pursuing studies in Master's" won't make much sense.